# Change tooltip's content to reflect those in html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltipster

I have the code below. What i want to achieve is when i hover those `h1` and `p`. the contents are output correctly and dynamically to the `tooltip`(`h1` ->This is heading,`p` -> this is paragraph). Now the `tooltip` output is fixed to `span(id = "tooltip_content")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/themes/tooltipster-light.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content">This is a Heading</h1>
<p class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content">This is a paragraph.</p>


<div style="display:none" class="tooltip_templates">
  <span id="tooltip_content">
       <strong>This is the content of my tooltip!</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I transformed your code into a runnable snippet, yet it doesn't have any tooltips showing up. Please add the missing pieces (I assume some CSS).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584458/uncaught-typeerror-tooltipster-is-not-a-function

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to showcase your problem in runnable snippets, so please don't edit your question back into a non-runnable state that doesn't properly refer the necessary assets. Instead, **add the missing pieces** .

Comment: i add the tooltip css file. The whole js and css files are from https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Answer (score 0):

From the `tooltipster` documentation (5.):

> Important: if you have two tooltips that have the same
>   data-tooltip-content attribute (that is to say, want to both use the
>   same HTML element), please set the contentCloning option to true when
>   you initialize your tooltips:
>
> ```
> $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
>   contentCloning: true }
> );
> ```

Comment: OK. I want the tooltip to show different contents. I removed the data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content" and add "contentCloning: true,content:$(this)," under the $('.tooltip').tooltipster. But somehow the $(this) jquery object doesn't work